# Function graph transformations

Tags: graphing-functions

I'm looking for a reliable document with formal mathematical justification of how and why graph transformations work. Given a function $f(x)$, what is the graph of $f(a-x)$? Why should we shift $f(x)$ by $a$ to the right in this case?
Imagine someone read a paper about graph transformations, like [this one](http://www.math.utah.edu/~wortman/1050-text-gt.pdf).

Intuitively, someone could say: well, $f(a-x)$ is a graph of $f(-x)$ shifted left by $a$ because we are adding $a$, right?
Is there a more elegant and formal way to prove what those transformations to graphs result in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the graph of a function $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb R$ to be the set of points
$$
G(f)=\{(x,f(x))\ \mid\ x\in D\}
$$
Then the function $g(x)=f(x-a)$ is defined whenever $x-a=y\in D$ so that $x\in E=\{y+a\ \mid y\in D\}$ and the graph is
$$
\begin{align}
G(g)&=\{(x,g(x))\ \mid\ x\in E\}\\
&=\{(x,f(x-a))\ \mid\ x\in E\}\\
&=\{(y+a,f((y+a)-a))\ \mid y\in D\}\\
&=\{(y+a,f(y))\ \mid y\in D\}
\end{align}
$$
So when you compare this last description of $G(g)$ to the description of $G(f)$ you see that
$$
(x,f(x))\in G(f)\iff(x+a,f(x))\in G(g)
$$
So the graph of $g$ contains all the same points as the graph of $f$ with the $x$-value of each point shifted by $a$.

**UPDATE:** In particular this means that for the function $h(x)=f(-x)$ we have $h(x-a)=f(-(x-a))=f(a-x)$ which has the same graph as $h$, but with the $x$-value of every point shifted by $a$.

Comment: Is it ok that you changed $y$ to $x$ here?:
${(y+a,f(y))\ \mid y\in D}$ and then you got: $(x,f(x))\in G(f)\iff(x+a,f(x))\in G(g)$.

Comment: @user4205580: Indeed! Both $x$ and $y$ belongs to the domain $D$ so they are really both names of variables to range over $D$ and produce the graphs $(x,f(x))$ and $(x+a,f(x))$ respectively.

Comment: Oh, I just remembered something. Is this statement correct? "The $x$-coordinates in the graph of $y=f(x)$ correspond to the $x$-coordinates in the graph of $y=f(cx)$ multiplied by $c$." I believe it should be the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of $x\mapsto f(x+a)$ is just the composition of $f$ with the translation $x\mapsto x+a$. Therefore, if $D$ is the domain of $f$, the graph of $x\mapsto f(x+a)$ is the same graph than $f$ but on the domain $D+a$.

Comment: Ok. How would you convince me that the graph of $f(a-x)$ is obtained by shifting $f(-x)$ to the right by $a$?

Comment: Why don't you draw the two functions ? take for exemple $f(x)=x$ or $f(x)=x^2$, you'll see immediately ! But actually, I don't have to convince you ! it's just logical !

Comment: You really think I can't see it? My point is how would you convince a person who can't.

Comment: to make a draw, it's the easier way to explain it :-)

Answer (score 0):

(Thinking of $a>0$, as it seems that you do)

You seem to be OK (correct me if I'm wrong) that $f(x-a)$ shifts the graph of $x\mapsto f(x)$ to the right with $a$ steps. OK?

Thus, to shift the function $x\mapsto f(-x)$ to the right $a$ steps, we want $f(-(x-a))=f(a-x)$.

Comment: Ok, but how do conclude that if $f(x-a)$ is shifted $a$ to the right, then $f(-(x-a))$ will shift the graph to the right as well? The purpose of this thread is to prove it with as little referring to intuition as possible.

Comment: @user4205580: I just updated my answer. In my update, I believe I gave the justification formally for what you originally asked. I hope you agree!